# Why is Uzzah's name spelled differently

Tags: names, aleph-bet-letters, samuel-shmuel-book-of, spelling-variants, book-of-chronicles

In 2 Shmuel chapter 6 Uzzah's name is spelled alternatively with an ending aleph (v. 3,6) or heh (v 7,8). What is the explanation for this change?

Note that in the recounting in 1 Divrei HaYamim 13 the name is spelled exclusively with an aleph.

Comment: Why are the names Yirmiyah, Yeshayah, Chizkiya spelled sometimes with a vav at the end and sometimes without? Why is Chizkiya sometimes spelled with a yud in the beginning? Why is Akiva sometimes with a heh and sometimes with an alef? Why is Yehoshua sometimes with a heh and sometimes without (Yeshua)? The list is endless, and the question pointless, this is just the way names work in Tanach!

Comment: @Bach if you could cite a source which supports what you say that would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: @Bach Where is Yehoshua spelled Yeshua?

Comment: @Loewian ezra 3:2; 10:18. They're obviously referring to the high priest yehoshua spelled with a heh in Chaggai 2:4 and zechariah 6:11.

Comment: Maybe it's a case of a Hebrew vs Aramaic ending, like with Akiva ending with an alef in the Talmud Bavli but a hey in the Yerushalmi.

Comment: @ezra there is no connection between them. In Yeshua the heh is in the middle, whereas in Akiva it is in the end of the word!

Comment: @Bach - He mentions that in the case of Uzzah, it's either an ending alef or ending hey. I'm not sure I get what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Bach there is almost always a reason as to why people's names are spelled in different ways, esp. if something is a rarity. Amnon's (Abshalom's half-brother) name is spelled "Aminon" in one place. There's a reason. Not every variation of the spelling of someone's name is simply "because that's how it is".